# Use eth0 and eth1 for different subnets and assigned host name to interface?

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp, hostname, sles

I have a machine running SELES 10 with dual NIC Both the NICs are on separate subnets. The server uses a DHCP.

So when one interface, `eth0`, gets the IP from DHCP and registers with DNS and then the other interface, `eth1`, gets an IP and registers with the DNS, it overwrites the DNS record.

#### Questions

- Is there a way I can keep both records in the DNS and be able to use the interfaces separately?
- I've come across an article titled: [14.3. Configuring a DHCP Client](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html), has anyone used the option `DHCP_hostname` where you can tie the interface to the hostname for the first `eth0` and `eth1` can be anything else?
- Has any one tested that?
- According to the article it would appear that it's possible, does that sound correct?

**NOTE:** The article mentioned above is for Red Hat based distros if that matters.